# Memory leaks passing dynamic variables recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-leaks

I have a recursive function that requires me to create a new array every time the function is called. The function also requires the array that was previously created:

```
void myFunc(int* prevArray)
{
int newSize;
//do some calculations to find newSize
int* newArray;
newArray = new int[newSize];
//do some calculations to fill newArray
//check some stopping condition
myFunc(newArray);
}
```

This function leaks memory, but I can't avoid that by adding

> delete[] newArray;

since I can only add that after calling the function again. How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the problem with doing `delete[] newArray;` after the call to `myFunc`?

Comment: Well, it would keep stacking up memory for as long as the recursion keeps going. The arrays are quite large, and I need to call this function a lot.

Comment: You can delete `prevArray` unless it equals nullptr.

Comment: @RobVerheyen Well that seems to be a natural consequence of your algorithm - each successive call to `myFunc` requires a large array computed by the previous call.

Comment: Doesn't prevArray get copied from the previous instance?

Comment: And currently it *does* stack up memory for as long as the recursion keeps going. The only problem now is, that you are not freeing this memory and adding delete[] after the function call will solve this. (stack up in terms of use - arrays are allocated on the heap)

Comment: @RobVerheyen Only a pointer is copied, not the whole big array.

Comment: Okay, so I could safely delete prevArray before the new function call, and newArray after the new function call, correct?

Comment: @RobVerheyen No, that would cause you to delete twice. The `prevArray` pointer is the same memory as `newArray` in the "outer" `myFunc`. One new - one delete. If you only need the old array in order to calculate a new one, perhaps you could reuse it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by making use of dynamic memory allocation.

```
// allocate initial size
const int INITIAL_SIZE = 5;
int *myArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * INITIAL_SIZE));

int myFunc(int *aArray, int numAllocated) {
    int numElements = calculateNewSize();

    if (numElements != numAllocated) {
        // allocate new size
        realloc(aArray, (numElements * sizeof(int));
    }

    return numElements;
}
```

Now you can call myFunc like this:

```
int numElements;

numElements = myFunc(myArray, numElements);
```

When your done using myFunc don't forget to free the memory

```
free(myArray);
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but a problem would be that the content of the newArray depend on the content of prevArray. I know that realloc perserves everything that was in the old memory block, but my newArray is not just my old array with things added to the end.  They represent matrices that have some linear algebra done between them.

Comment: I don't see the problem, why don't you initialize the array then? The number of elements is a given variable so it is easy to write an initialization function to iterate over all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
void myFunc(int* prevArray)
{
    int newSize;
    ...newArray = new int[newSize];
    myFunc(newArray);
    delete[] newArray;
}
```

or better yet use std::unique_ptr to control the newArray memory. In this way you will follow the rule of thumb regarding dynamic memory - that it should have one owner, responsible for both allocating and freeing it.

Answer (score 1):

You might just use a vector and swap the new result into the final result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct X { ~X() { std::cout << "Destruction\n"; } };
void recursive(unsigned n, std::vector<X>& result) {
    // Put new_result in a scope for destruction
    {
        std::vector<X> new_result(1);

        // Do something

        // The previous result is no longer needed
        std::swap(result, new_result);
    }

    // Next recursion
    if(n) {
        std::cout << "Call\n";
        recursive(--n, result);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<X> result(1);
    std::cout << "Call\n";
    recursive(3, result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understand what you mean. Is the struct meant to contain my array?

Comment: No, it's intention is just to show the point of deletion - std::vector<int> would be your choice